# Lighttpd on WinCE

Tags: windows-ce, cross-compiling, lighttpd, mqx

Has anyone successfully cross-compiled Lighttpd to use on WinCE?
On the Lighttpd wiki it says it supports Windows OS's but on the actual Lighttpd site it doesn't.

If Lighttpd does not work on WinCE, can you recommend another web-server that is:

- open source
- free
- supports multi-platforms such as WinCE, and perhaps other RTOS's like MQX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CE has a [built in webserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834461.aspx), if included in your OS image by your vendor.   Or if you're creating your own image with Platform Builder, use `SYSGEN_HTTPD=1`.

I know its not open source, but its free.

Any reason that wouldn't work for you?

Comment: I don't have PB installed on this machine, but I believe all of the source for the HTTPD server in CE *is* included in the install.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Win CE's built in webserver, but what I am trying to do is just use the server as a simple RESTful solution to accept POST JSON/XML request from a client application, and then be able to use that to execute applications internal to the device, and respond back to the client.